# Money Transaction without using in-app purchase for iphone app

Tags: iphone

I want to implement the payment gateway like functionality in my iphone application other than In-App Purchase feature provided by Apple.

So, i have one Question regarding the application approval on Appstore that, if i will redirect user to the UIwebview for payment related functionality, then apple will reject this application for not following the human interface guideline or it will allow this.

Other way i can do it by calling web-service for the transaction of money. So, again there is any chance of app rejection on AppStore.

Please share your thought on this

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely no way you'll be allowed to do this. Check the news the past couple of days. Apple is demanding even giants like Amazon and Sony to go with the In-App purchasing.

**Edit** Actually, Apple did come out with a softer stance, saying that you'd have to offer both payment options if you did your own transactions. So there's that..

Comment: thnks for the quick update on my query.But i am not getting your point for "you'd have to offer both payment options"? can you please elaborate more on this.